# Laravel - The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: apache, htaccess, laravel-5

## O que eu fiz

Fiz um formulário que faz o cadastro dos dados no banco de dados. Localmente ele funcionou perfeitamente.

## Problema

Ele simplesmente diz que não está encotrando a URL. É estranho, pois o erro abaixo diz que o index.php do public não foi encontrado, e caso estejam se perguntando, o **action** do formulário está certo, ele está chamando o método `gerarPdf`.

*The requested URL /var/www/laravel/barcodeAssinatura/public/index.php was not found on this server.*

## url acessada

https://osite.com.br/pasta/barcode/

### public/.htacces

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

### routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::post('gerarPdf', 'HomeController@gerarPdf');
```

**OBS**: Foi criado um Alias para que ao acessar o site ele chame o *public/index.php*.

Comment: Também estou com um erro assim. A rota post está retornando erro 301 Moved Permanently quando eu tento acessar por ajax. Porém a rota existe e é encontrada quando envio o formulário pela url de navegador.

Comment: Seu servidor é linux? você verificou se o mod_rewrite do apache está habilitado? A url que você especificou acima não condiz com os dados informados do route.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eu resolvi esse problema removendo essa linha do .httaccess: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]`